# Get the ARN of the SNS topic that Cognito uses for SMS messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I'm setting up a new app that will use a Cognito User Pool. I would like to send SMS messages to my users for authentication. There are plenty of examples out there of setting this up, however every one of them that I have seen attaches an inline policy to the IAM role used by Cognito to send messages to SNS that uses "*" as the policy resource.

I would prefer to limit this role to ONLY publishing to the SNS topic needed to send SMS messages, rather than giving it permissions to publish to any SNS topic in my account.

How do I find the ARN of the SNS topic that AWS uses for sending SMS messages in my account? I've been unable to find that information in the documentation ,and neither the web GUI nor the AWS CLI shows an SNS topic in my account that has any SMS-related subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Cognito does not leverage a topic to publish SMS through SNS. Instead, it targets the destination phone number directly as the resource (as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html#sms_publish_console)). To keep Cognito from being able to publish to any of the topics in your account, you could try extending your IAM role policy with something like:

```
{
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "sns:Publish",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*"
  }]
}
```

which would still allow Cognito to publish directly to phone numbers (as the "resource" in that case would just be the phone number).